# PHP Date format

Tags: php

`Tue Oct 26 10:39:39 +0000 2010`

How to convert format to `2010-10-26`

Comment: What is the code used to output the first line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("Tue Oct 26 10:39:39 +0000 2010"))
// 2010-10-26
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the DateTime object:

```
echo date_format(new DateTime('Tue Oct 26 10:39:39 +0000 2010'), 'Y-m-d');
```

or:

```
$date = new DateTime('Tue Oct 26 10:39:39 +0000 2010');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```